# SQL UNION GROUP BY Pagination

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core, union

I'm trying to compose a UNION query between 2 tables and paginate the results. The problem is the INNER JOINS results in duplicate parent rows in the results so the pagination is incorrect.

I've created a dummy db to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

[Here's the schema diagram]

[image: 1]

This is the SQL I have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 'Delivery' as [table_name]
    ,[Delivery].Id
    ,[Delivery].StreetAddress
    ,[Delivery].City
    ,[Delivery].[State]
    ,[Delivery].Zip
    ,[Delivery].Longitude
    ,[Delivery].Latitude    
    ,[Delivery].OrderId
    ,[Order].[Date] AS 'Date'
    ,[Order].Total AS 'Total'
    ,[OrderProduct].[Name]
FROM [Delivery]
INNER JOIN [Order] ON [Delivery].OrderId = [Order].Id
INNER JOIN [OrderProduct] ON [Order].Id = [OrderProduct].OrderId

UNION

SELECT 'Collection' as [table_name]
    ,[Collection].Id
    ,[Collection].StreetAddress
    ,[Collection].City
    ,[Collection].[State]
    ,[Collection].Zip
    ,[Collection].Longitude
    ,[Collection].Latitude  
    ,[Collection].OrderId
    ,[Order].[Date] AS 'Date'
    ,[Order].Total AS 'Total'
    ,[OrderProduct].[Name]
FROM [Collection]
INNER JOIN [Order] ON [Collection].OrderId = [Order].Id
INNER JOIN [OrderProduct] ON [Order].Id = [OrderProduct].OrderId

) AS Result

ORDER BY Result.Id

OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY

GO
```

There are multiple OrderProducts per Order so the results contain duplicate Result.Id. I've tried to use GROUP BY on the Result.Id but I get this error 'Column 'Result.table_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.' How do I achieve correct pagination in this scenario?

Furthermore I need to consume the results in EntityFramework Core 2.2. Unfortunately I can't upgrade to a later version.

Many thanks

Comment: try to use `Distinct` as simpliest solution

Comment: I'm still getting duplicate Result.Id using the Distinct keyword